# Angular - ng-pick-datetime: how to initialize the input value in a reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a form using a popular date time picker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime). I tried to initialize the value of the DateTime input, but no luck so far (event the default value is not set in form)

Please refer to my sample code for detail
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-pick-datetime-format-i18n-bh5lqi?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of using strings, try using actual date objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credited to @MikeOne's comment, I had verified that you need to set the date with `Date` object or `Moment` object.

### Method 1: (Date String to Date)

```js
this.itineraryrForm.setValue({
  arrivalTime: new Date("01/01/2021 23:00")
});
```

### Or Method 2: (Date String to Moment with specified Date string format)

```js
this.itineraryrForm.setValue({
  arrivalTime: moment("01/01/2021 23:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
});
```

[Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-pick-datetime-format-i18n-4hy2vz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Note**: You are recommended to remove `[(ngModel)]` binding if you use `[formControl]` as [it has been deprecated in Angular v6](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel).